# How to fix: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'create_at

Tags: sql, laravel

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'create_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = 2 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null order by `create_at` desc) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)

I've tried: php artisan migrate: fresh

index.blade.php

```
<div class="col-9 pt-5">
           <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline font-weight-bold"><h1>{{ $user->username }}</h1>
            <a href="/p/create">Add New Post</a>
           </div>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div ><strong>{{ $user->posts->count() }}</strong> posts</div>
                    <div class="pl-5"><strong>23k</strong> followers</div>
                    <div class="pl-5"><strong>435</strong> following</div>
                </div>
                <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold" ><strong>{{ $user->profile->title }}</strong></div>
                <div>{{ $user->profile->description }}</div>
                <div><a href="#">{{ $user->profile->url ??'N/A' }}</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        @foreach($user->$posts as $post)
        <div class="col-4" >
            <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100"> 
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

User.php file----

```
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('create_at','desc');
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
```

post.php file

```
class Post extends Model
{
     protected $guarded=[];
   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown column `create_at` and known is `created_at`

In your file User.php

change

```
return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('create_at','desc');
```

to

```
return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
```

Comment: After changing, I get that error.
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: index.blade.php file
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div ><strong>{{ $user->posts->count() }}</strong> posts</div>
                </div>
                <div><strong>{{ $user->profile->title }}</strong></div>
                <div>{{ $user->profile->description }}</div>
                <div><a href="#">{{ $user->profile->url ??'N/A' }}</a></div>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div>
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <div class="col-4" >
            <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100"> 
        </div>
        @endforeach

Comment: @AnikaTabassum do @dump($user->profile) at top of your blade and give me output

Comment: I'm using this:
{{ $user->profile? $user->profile->title:"" }}

replace of this {{$user->profile->title}} and it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mistake

```php
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
    }
```

Comment: After changing, I get that error. Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

The default laravel timestamp attribute for creation date is **`created_at`** not `create_at`

Comment: After changing, I get that error. Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)